# Cannot restore a saved machine

Tags: virtualization, qemu

I cannot restore a saved machine with both virt-manager and the virtsh restore command:

```
laurent@aspire6930g:/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/save$ sudo virsh restore windows7.save 
erreur : Impossible de restaurer le domaine depuis windows7.save
erreur : internal error: cannot load AppArmor profile 'libvirt-df3939ed-3ba9-12f4-b382-8f4337f9ddc6'
```

I googled a lot about it but without help.

Is it anything special I forgot to configure ?

Comment: Have you tried putting that AppArmor profile on complain mode `sudo aa-complain /etc/apparmor.d/libvirt-df3939ed-3ba9-12f4-b382-8f4337f9ddc6`